# Floppy-based linux distro for backing up an old PC

Tags: linux-distributions

Is there a linux distro that fits on a 3.5 inch floppy that I could use to backup an entire harddrive of an old PC? (1997) It cannot boot from CD. It also has a network card, so it could theoretically download stuff from the internet (or run it from the CD once the floppy-based linux is booted).

Comment: Initiate a CD-boot from the floppy, old Linux distros were able to do so... That brings up memories from a long time ago. You might be lucky googling that.

Comment: That would be absolutely ideal. Can you elaborate how to achieve that? It woulf be a very elegant solution to my problem.

Comment: If you can load but not boot off a cd - there's bootloaders like [plop](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) that you can boot off a floppy then use to boostrap a more 'full' OS

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, this was it! Super simple. I downloaded Plop Boot Manager 5 (which is the only one supporting floppy boot) and am already running clonezilla. Please add this as an answer and I will tick it as the solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to bootstrap the install with a bootloader that'll boot of a floppy and use that to boot an ISO.

While there's other options - the 'older'/'stable' version of [plop](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) should let you bootstrap booting into a CD drive or other 'modern' media that the older PC doesn't support, and you can proceed from there.